# Spring aspect ordering

Tags: spring, aspectj, spring-aop

What would be the order of invocations on the "way in" if I have 3 aspects like:

```
@Order(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE)
public class Aspect1

public class Aspect2

@Order(Ordered.LOWEST_PRECEDENCE)
public class Aspect3
```

so Aspect2 doesn't have any order annotation.

It is clear that Aspect1 will be invoked before Aspect3, but does it mean that Aspect2 will be always invoked in between ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the official javadoc about [@Order](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/annotation/Order.html):

> Annotation that defines ordering. The value is optional, and represents order value as defined in the Ordered interface. Lower values have higher priority. The default value is Ordered.LOWEST_PRECEDENCE, indicating lowest priority (losing to any other specified order value).

This means that `Aspect2` will also have a value of `Ordered.LOWEST_PRECEDENCE`, which is `Integer.MAX_VALUE`. I don't think there is a way of being 100% sure that it will always be invoked before `Aspect3` - I believe it depends on the order of component scan.

If you want to be sure, you can put in exact values:

```
@Order(1)
public class Aspect1 {...}

@Order(2)
public class Aspect2 {...}

@Order(3)
public class Aspect3 {...}
```

Or just put a value between `Integer.MIN_VALUE` and `Integer.MAX_VALUE` on `Aspect2`:

```
@Order(0)
public class Aspect2 {...}
```

Here is also a test which confirms this:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@SpringApplicationConfiguration(classes =
    {Class1.class, Class3.class, Class2.class})
public class TestTest {

    public static interface Test {}

    @Order(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE)
    @Component
    public static class Class1 implements Test {}

    @Order
    @Component
    public static class Class2 implements Test {}

    @Order(Ordered.LOWEST_PRECEDENCE)
    @Component
    public static class Class3 implements Test {}

    @Autowired
    List<Test> list;

    @Test
    public void test() {
        System.out.println("list: " + list);
    }
}
```

This will output:

```
list: [TestTest$Class1@d21a74c, TestTest$Class3@6e509ffa, TestTest$Class2@2898ac89]
```

But if you change the order of classes `2` and `3` in `@SpringApplicationConfiguration`, `Class2` will be invoked second.

Comment: Thank you, great response, but it's still not clear what would be the order if some aspect will be without Order annotation.

Comment: You cannot be sure what the order will be. It would be the same as if both Aspect2 and Aspect3 had `@Order(Ordered.LOWEST_PRECEDENCE)`, and thus it depends on the order the classes are scanned (or defined) at runtime, but you should not rely on that in production.